# Eliminate empty categories based on result?

Tags: mysql

How would I return all category id's related to the result of a query?

```
items_cats: (many to many)
product_id | category_id
====================
1          |  1
1          |  2
1          |  4
1          |  7

2          |  1
2          |  3
2          |  4
2          |  7

3          |  1
3          |  3
3          |  4
3          |  8
```

In the query below I get all the product id's that contain category_id 3 and category_id 7.
But I also like to know which category_id's (options) still have producs_id's base on the selection:

For example I like this query to return (based on code example):
-product_id = 2
-category_id's: 7, 3, 4, 1

When using this I'll probably like to limet the query for max items per page.

code I;ve got so far:

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT t1.product_id, t1.category_id
    FROM 
      items_cats t1   
    INNER JOIN
       items_cats t1b 
       ON t1.product_id =t1b.product_id 
    WHERE
      t1.category_id=3 AND
      t1b.category_id=7
```

Problem in loose query for the cat id's:

```
    SELECT 
       e1.category_id
    FROM 
      drinks_ingredients e1     
    WHERE
      e1.category_id=2
```

Of course It returns 2 but I like it to return  1, 2, 4, 7.

The other way around work but how would I make this efficient with a lot of products and categories? Would I be possible to combine those query's.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.category_id
    FROM  items_cats t1
    WHERE t1.product_id = 2
```

Comment: was a mistake changed it to what it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but here is one.

First, we need to work out which `product_id`s we're interested in. You can count how many of the required categories each `product_id` is in:

```
SELECT product_id, count(category_id) as numcats
FROM items_cats 
WHERE category_id IN (3,7) 
GROUP BY product_id;
+------------+---------+
| product_id | numcats |
+------------+---------+
|          1 |       1 |
|          2 |       2 |
|          3 |       1 |
+------------+---------+
```

Since we specified two `category_id` (3 and 7), we are only interested in `product_id` where `count(category_id) = 2`. So add a `HAVING numcats=2` to the end:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(category_id) as numcats
FROM items_cats 
WHERE category_id IN (3,7) 
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING numcats=2;
# (returns all product_id with both category_id=3 and 7.
```

So here are all the `product_id`s we want the `category_id`s for.
Then we just select all `category_id` where `product_id` is in the previous table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_id
FROM items_cats
WHERE product_id IN
  (SELECT product_id
  FROM items_cats 
  WHERE category_id IN (3,7) 
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(category_id)=2);

+-------------+
| category_id |
+-------------+
|           1 |
|           3 |
|           4 |
|           7 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Tank you for your solution. I'm gone do some performance testing. Would you think using a nested set db design would speed up the query's time for this case?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about database design models in terms of performance :(